# Is this important to install sql server with an windows application set up

Tags: sql, .net

I have developed a application in c# which is windows based application. It stores data into database sql server. I want to know, when I create setup in VS and install it in a client computer should I install sql server software also or Is there any way without installing SQL Server in client's PC  My application can function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

sIf you use a filebased implementaion of SQL (localDB) you should be able to get away with a "setup" installing the neccecary dependencies to bootstrap the DB. (Someone correct me?)

If you use the DB in a hosted SQL environment (SQL Server running as a service), you will need to install SQL server on the deployed pc, and get the database up.

I am no sure if you can "automate" installing SQL server and getting the DB up from a setup app.

Answer (score 0):

You have two deployment options for applications that contain SQL Server Compact 3.5 databases. The method of deployment you choose depends on the servicing requirements of your application and whether your users will need administrative credentials on the computer on which the application will be installed.

Following are the deployment options for SQL Server Compact 3.5 databases:
1. Traditional Microsoft Windows Installer (Microsoft setup technology)
a. Users need administrative credentials to install the application.
b. SQL Server Compact 3.5 will be serviced by Microsoft Update.
c. Can use ClickOnce deployment.

-or-

Private file–based deployment (deploying the SQL Server Compact 3.5 DLLs as part of the project)
 1. Users do not need administrative credentials to install the application.
 2. SQL Server Compact 3.5 will not be serviced by Microsoft Update.
 3. Can also use ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: I am using app.config file for connection string so that later on client pc i can make changes as well. Yes there is User Name and Password as well in app.config file which belongs to SQl Server 2008.